# How to solve this pointer error? (from incompatible pointer type)

Tags: c, pointers, casting, unsigned-integer, libconfig

I've this function:(myvariable is un unsigned int)
**config_setting_lookup_int64 is the libconfig.h function -> int config_lookup_int64 (const config t * config, [Function]
const char * path, long long * value)**

config_setting_lookup_int64(file, "myvariable", &myvariable);

I can see this warning: **passing argument 3 of 'config_setting_lookup_int64' from incompatible pointer type**

To solve the problem, I tried to write:

```
config_setting_lookup_int64(file, "myvariable", myvariable);
```

But I can see another warning: **passing argument 3 of 'config_setting_lookup_int64' makes pointer from integer without a cast**. How can I solve the problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: it's the libconfig function int config_lookup_int64 (const config t * config, [Function]
const char * path, long long * value)

Comment: so why don't you make `myvariable` `long long`? C is generally more strict about pointer types so if it asks for `long long *` you're going to need to pass a `long long *`.

Comment: you're right! I was not careful! my fault!